# PHP giving fatal error on comparing dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have one date in database, and I want to compare it with the current date. So I write the following function:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$today_date = $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

function do_diifernce($date_1, $date_2) {
    $my_date = $date_1;
    $createDate = new DateTime($my_date);
    $strip = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
    $difference = $date_2->diff($createDate, true);
    $difference->total_difference = $difference->y . "." . $difference->m;
    return $difference;
}

$comparison = do_diifernce($databse_date, $today_date);
```

So

```
$databse_date = 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000
$today_date = 2019-05-06 10:48:01
```

But I can't print the value of `$comparison`.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string

How can I solve it?

Comment: you got error here `$difference = $date_2->diff($createDate, true);`

Comment: try to check if $createDate, is a string or not

Comment: Replace your first line with $datetime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

Comment: @Ahmed_Ali What is that supposed to change? It looks completely redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were playing date 2 as string which should be treated as datetime object to get the difference between two datetime objects.

```
function do_diifernce($date_1, $date_2)
{

    $createDate1                  = new DateTime($date_1);
    $createDate2                  = new DateTime($date_2);
    $difference                   = $createDate2->diff($createDate1);
    $sign = ($createDate1 < $createDate2 ? '-':'+');
    $difference->total_difference = $difference->format("%r%a");
    return $difference;
}
$databse_date = "2019-05-01 00:00:00";
$today_date   = "2019-05-06 10:48:01";
$comparison   = do_diifernce($databse_date, $today_date);
print_r($comparison);die;
```

Here is official [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

You check that array as there is no difference of year and month as both dates belongs to same month and year so its coming 0.0

Comment: this is very helpful . But could you please help us for if the $date_1 is less than $date_2 then it return wrong details . like $date_1=2019-05-01 00:00:00 $date_2=2019-05-06 10:48:01  . Then it should return -5 but currently it return +5

Comment: can i check total_difference is less than 0 ? how can i check ?

Comment: Check I added format to get date difference in signs with `%r%a`

Comment: if($comparison->total_difference <0 ){
 echo 'lesser';
}
else{
 echo 'greter';
}  i write this code . but it showing greater . But it should show lesser

Comment: @abilasher I have made changes in code, Once check `d` property of comparison variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192892/discussion-between-abilash-er-and-rahul-meshram).

Answer (score 3):

You pass in `$today_date` to `do_diifernce()`, which is a string (as you have formatted it with `format()`). You can either pass `$today` in (which is an object), or include a condition that checks if its an object or not.

```php
function do_difference($date_1, $date_2) {
    // Check if the arguments were DateTime objects - if not, instantiate them as that
    if (!($date_1 instanceof DateTime)) {
        $date_1 = new DateTime($date_1);
    } 
    if (!($date_2 instanceof DateTime)) {
        $date_2 = new DateTime($date_2);
    } 

    // Compare the difference and return the Y and m properties
    $difference = $date_2->diff($date_1);
    $difference->total = $difference->y . "." . $difference->m;
    return $difference;
}

$today = new DateTime();
$comparison = do_difference($databse_date, $today);
```

Comment: $date_1=2019-05-01 00:00:00 $date_2=2019-05-06 10:48:01 . Then it should return -5 but currently it return +5

Comment: That's because you set the `absolute` argument of `DateTime::diff()` to true. Remove it (so it becomes default `false`) and you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

You got an error here: `$difference = $date_2->diff($createDate, true);`. AFAIK, the `diff()` function is deprecated after PHP 5.3.

If you want to calculate the difference between two dates, you can use `date_diff` as follows.

```
<?php
    $date1 = date_create("2000-04-01");
    $date2 = date_create("2019-04-06");
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
?>
```

Comment: `diff` is not deprecated

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt what happened to it? can't find any reference to diff() in php

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error, because you call `format` on date2, which returns a string, no DateTime object.

Remove the call to format, then your comparison should work.

All you have to do, is to replace the last line with the following:

```
$comparison=do_diifernce($databse_date, $today);
```

Comment: Can you please do a `var_dump` of `$today` and `$databse_date`? Also, what does `not work` mean? What does it do, what error does it give you?